# C# Is it possible to change HTML from the web browser?

Tags: c#, html, email, templates, browser

I´m wondering if it could be possible to change the HTML document text directly from the web Browser.
I´m currently working on an email client, which uses a html template for the design.

Everything seems good but I need to configure the template.

Like I said, the template is stored in a rich textbox, which is invisible.
Basically I can see the web Browser with its template, only.
Now I want to insert my custom text to the template.

Is it possible to change the htmldocumenttext directly from the webbrowser ?
Is there another way to edit the content of the template ?

Answer (score 0):

You bet it's possible. Whole libraries are written around modifying the HTML after initial delivery to the browser. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp. Then maybe: https://jquery.com/